# How to send Dual slider Min and Max Value to PHP via POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to send min val and max val to php using submit via dual slider bar

The static page call the server php

```
    <?php include('server/server.php') ?>
```

JS code is down below

```
  <script>$( function() {
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
  range: true,
  min: 18,
  max: 100,
  values: [ 18, 30 ],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
  " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );  } );  </script>
```

And HTML Code is Looks down below
At the moment, i have only submit the age. However, i want to send Min val and Max val.

```
<form action = "edit_preference2.php" method = "POST">   
<p>
  <label for="amount">Show Me:</label>
  <!--At the Moment it's only send 'AGE' 
  However i want to send min and max to PHP -->
  <input type="text" id="age" name = "age" readonly style="border:0;             color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>

<div id="slider-range"></div>
<button type="submit" name="btn_preference">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to send this Min and Max value of Slider var to PHP

And in my PHP server. receive the data like down below

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_preference'])) 
{
$amount = $_POST["age"];
#How can i receive min and Max val ?? 
$_SESSION = $amount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create 2 hidden inputs with name and id as min and max,
then in your event

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    $( "#min" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
    $( "#max" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
}
```

then you'll just access them in your PHP as

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_preference'])) 
{
$amount = $_POST["age"];
$min = $_POST["min"];
$max = $_POST["max"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send a POST request using JQUERY AJAX post request.

```
     $.ajax({
url: 'server.php',
method: 'post',
data:  "max=" + max + "&min=" + min  ,
processData: false,
success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){

    if(data=="done")
    {
        alert("done"
    }
    else{
        alert("not done");

    }
},
error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
    alert( errorThrown );
}
});
```